# how can we handle exceptions with bigquery functions?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

given any function like e.g:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ds.fn(param ANY TYPE) RETURNS STRING AS (
    (SELECT 1/0)
);
```

Is there a way for handling errors when the statement fails and return a default value?

Note: My question is about **any error** that a select statement can throw and not only the arithmetic in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your function more robust using SAFE functions inside a UDF and also make it return default value if it fails like below.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION ds.fn(param ANY TYPE) RETURNS AS ((
  SELECT IFNULL(SAFE_DIVIDE(1,0), 0)
));
```

Also, you can catch a error in a BigQuery script using `BEGIN...EXCEPTION` block:

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#beginexceptionend

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION testset.fn(param ANY TYPE) RETURNS FLOAT64 AS ((
  SELECT 1/0
));

BEGIN
  SELECT testset.fn(10);
EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
  SELECT @@error.message;
END;
```

Comment: thanks @Jaytiger, but the need is not specific for arithmetic errors, i am looking for a way for handling any kind of error that a select statement can throw

Comment: If you want to catch error in multi statements,  you can consider `BEGIN...EXCEPTION` in my updated answer.

Comment: cool, that's exactly what i am trying to do but inside a function and then return a default value